# Type date default sysdate in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have seen this question before but it is not answered, so here it goes:

When creating a table, I have a column with the type Date. I want that the default value is the system date, (Sysdate), but for some reason it does not work and it gives an error (in syntax, which is strange because I am following the Mysql syntax).

```
create table students(
id integer(10),
name varchar (21) NOT NULL, 
surname varchar(30),
grade integer check(grade in(1,2,3),
enrollment date default sysdate,
primary key(id) );
```

And it gives an error in syntax just at the "sysdate". I have tried with sys_date, sys-date, and it is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `sysdate`, try `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` like:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    creation_time      DATETIME DEFAULT   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modification_time  DATETIME ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```